# How can I add a gap between the bars in Recharts Bar chart (vertical, stacked)

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, stacked-chart, recharts

I'm trying to set up Recharts to display a vertical stacked barchart with some gap between the bars, but I'm not able to set any gap.

This is how my code looks like.

```js
<ResponsiveContainer height={23} width={'100%'}>
  <BarChart
    data={data}
    layout={'vertical'}
    barGap={10}
    margin={{ top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }}
  >
    <XAxis type={'number'} hide domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} />
    <YAxis
      dataKey='axis'
      type={'category'}
      axisLine={false}
      tickLine={false}
      hide
    />
    {keys.map((key: string, index: number) => (
      <Bar key={key} stackId={'stack'} dataKey={key} fill={colors[key]} />
    ))}
  </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>;
```

Comment: barCategoryGap might solve your issue

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue. Non of the presented bar properties have any effect on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

To add a gap between the bars, you could add another `Bar` component, that would have a fixed value, `fill`ed with a transparent color, so that you can have an illusion of gap between two bars in a stacked bar.

To have the gap value however, you'll need to update the `data` array beforehand, to add the `gap` value with its fixed value (set to `100` for example).

With this workaround, the solution could look like this:
[image]

Here's the associated code to the image:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid } from 'recharts';

const data = [
  /* Add the gap key to each data line; could also be done in a forloop */
  { name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400, gap: 100 },
  { name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210, gap: 100 },
  { name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290, gap: 100 },
  { name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000, gap: 100 },
  { name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181, gap: 100 },
  { name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500, gap: 100 },
  { name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100, gap: 100 },
];

const keys = ['uv', 'pv'];
const colors = ['#8884d8', '#82ca9d'];

export default class Example extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <BarChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={data}
        margin={{ top: 20, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
        layout='vertical'
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis type='number' />
        <YAxis type='category' dataKey='name' />
        {keys.map((key: string, index: number): any => {
          const bars = [];
          bars.push(<Bar dataKey={key} stackId="a" fill={colors[index]} />);
          /* Add a bar just for the gap after each bar */
          bars.push(<Bar dataKey='gap' stackId="a" fill='transparent' />);
          return bars;
        })}
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working stylistically by adding
`style={{ stroke: '#fff', strokeWidth: 2 }}` to `<BarChart>`:

```
<BarChart
  layout="vertical"
  data={barChartData}
  height={300}
  barSize={24}
  barCategoryGap={16}
  style={{ stroke: '#fff', strokeWidth: 2 }}
>
```

If you were to add empty `<Bar />` data to achieve this, you might encounter some weirdness once you start using Tooltips on the chart.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this @tL4302. I did a version of this.  The problem I found with this answer is that the bottom bar ends up with a border stroke that goes over the baseline tick line.  to avoid that, I only added this to the upper stacked bars and made them slightly thicker barSize so that they all align after.